# windows batch get the last business day before today

Tags: batch-file

I have to execute a batch file every day that returns the date of last business day in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`.

I tried this solution

```
@echo off
rem AddBusinessDays.bat date numOfDays 
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

rem Convert the date to Julian Day Number + number of days 
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%1") do (
  set /A mm=10%%a %% 100, dd=10%%b %% 100, yy=%%c 
)
set /A a=mm-14, jd=(1461*(yy+4800+a/12))/4+(367*(mm-2-12*(a/12)))/12-(3*((yy+4900+a/12)/100))/4+dd-32075+2+%2, dow=jd%%7

rem Adjust Julian Day Number to avoid weekends 
if %dow% lss 2 set /A jd+=2-dow

rem Convert Julian Day Number back to date 
set /A l=jd+68569-2,n=(4*l)/146097,l=l-(146097*n+3)/4,i=(4000*(l+1))/1461001,l=l-(1461*i)/4+31,j=(80*l)/2447,dd=l-(2447*j)/80,l=j/11,mm=j+2-(12*l),yy=100*(n-49)+i+l

rem Assemble the result 
if %dd% lss 10 set dd=0%dd% 
if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm% 
set newDate=%dd%%mm%%yy% 
echo %newDate%
```

but i should write the date manually

Comment: It would be way easier to write this in a *real* programming/scripting language. If it has to be batch, be sure you account for Holidays too. This list of holidays will likely depend on what days your business acknowledges. For reference, the NETWORKDAYS function in Excel would be a great tool for checking your work. That being said, you should update your question with what you have tried so far, not just present SO with a list of requirements.

Comment: Certainly if you've "tried many solutions", you should be able to [edit] your question and include at least one of them, and explain how it's not working the way you need.

Comment: Yes I know but sometimes we are obliged to code some scripts in a foreign language , is there any solution to obtain at least the "today-1"

Comment: **1** what is the last business day? Worldwide? **2** what _solutions_ did you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This VBS script has a modification that will return the previous Friday if the date chosen turns out to be a Saturday or Sunday:

```
:: Date backward and skipping weekends
@echo off
if "%~2"=="" (
echo to get yesterdays date use     call "%~n0" today -1
echo.
echo Add a third parameter if you want a separator in the date string
echo EG: for this format YYYY-MM-DD using yesterdays date
echo     call "%~n0" today -1 -
echo.
pause
goto :EOF)

set date1=%1
set qty=%2
set separator=%~3
if /i "%date1%" EQU "TODAY" (set date1=now) else (set date1="%date1%")
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,%date1%)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         d
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
endlocal& set "YY=%result:~0,4%" & set "MM=%result:~4,2%" & set "DD=%result:~6,2%" & set "daynum=%result:~-1%"
:: if the daynum is a weekend then run the batch file again to get the friday
set "weekend="
if %daynum% EQU 1 set /a weekend=qty - 2
if %daynum% EQU 7 set /a weekend=qty - 1
if defined weekend %0 %1 %weekend%

set "day=%YY%%separator%%MM%%separator%%DD%"
echo %%day%% is set to "%day%" (without the quotes)
echo %%YY%% is set to %YY%
echo %%MM%% is set to %MM%
echo %%DD%% is set to %DD%
echo.
echo daynum is "%daynum%"
echo daynum=1 Sunday 
echo daynum=2 Monday 
echo daynum=3 Tuesday 
echo daynum=4 Wednesday 
echo daynum=5 Thursday 
echo daynum=6 Friday 
echo daynum=7 Saturday
```

Here's a VBS script to get yesterdays date

```
:: Date forward & backward
@echo off
if "%~2"=="" (
echo to get todays date use         call "%~n0" today 0
echo to get yesterdays date use     call "%~n0" today -1
echo to get 25 days before 19441213 call "%~n0" 1944/12/13 -25
echo to get 1250 days in the future call "%~n0" today 1250
echo.
echo Add a third parameter if you want a separator in the date string
echo EG: for this format YYYY-MM-DD using today's date
echo     call "%~n0" today 0 -
echo.
pause
goto :EOF)

set date1=%1
set qty=%2
set separator=%~3
if /i "%date1%" EQU "TODAY" (set date1=now) else (set date1="%date1%")
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,%date1%)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         d
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
endlocal& (
set "YY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "daynum=%result:~-1%"
)
if %daynum% EQU 1 set "weekday=Sunday"
if %daynum% EQU 2 set "weekday=Monday"
if %daynum% EQU 3 set "weekday=Tuesday"
if %daynum% EQU 4 set "weekday=Wednesday"
if %daynum% EQU 5 set "weekday=Thursday"
if %daynum% EQU 6 set "weekday=Friday"
if %daynum% EQU 7 set "weekday=Saturday"

set "day=%YY%%separator%%MM%%separator%%DD%"
echo %%day%% is set to "%day%" (without the quotes)
echo %%YY%% is set to %YY%
echo %%MM%% is set to %MM%
echo %%DD%% is set to %DD%
echo The weekday turns out to be: %weekday%
pause
```

Comment: how  can I exclude the weekend 
eg: if today is monday --> today -1 --> returns the date of Friday

Comment: Check my edited answer - the top script is modified to skip weekends when going backward.

Comment: can we make a chat session ?

Comment: woow very nice 
now i wont to look for the file so i write :
"IF EXIST {C:\GS\Batch\JS_%YY%%MM%%DD%_LED.bat} (call C:\Gridshare\Batch\JS_%YY%%MM%%DD%_LED.bat) else echo JS_%YY%%MM%%DD%_LED.bat file not exisit"
but very time i execute i get : "...file not exisist  "

Comment: Hi again,
 now i'm trying to fix inputs (always today -1) how can i change it in the code 
i try :
echo off
set date1=today
set qty=-1
set separator=%~3
---
but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

This code is designed to get yesterdays date, but if it is Saturday or Sunday then it will return the previous Friday.

```
@echo off
set qty=-1
:loop4weekends
set "separator="
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,now)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         d
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
endlocal& set "YY=%result:~0,4%" & set "MM=%result:~4,2%" & set "DD=%result:~6,2%" & set "daynum=%result:~-1%"
:: if the daynum is a weekend then loop to get the friday
set "weekend="
echo %daynum%
if %daynum% EQU 1 set weekend=1&set "qty=-3"
if %daynum% EQU 7 set weekend=1&set "qty=-2"
if defined weekend goto :loop4weekends

set "day=%YY%%separator%%MM%%separator%%DD%"
echo %%day%% is set to "%day%" (without the quotes)
pause
```

Comment: when i run the batch file nothing happen

Comment: It sets the `%day%` variable and echoes it to the console here.  Are you clicking on it with a mouse?

Comment: no , first of all i open a cmd console then I call the file.
even when i double click on the batch file nothing happen just a black screen appear

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code above into a batch file?  It works fine here, considering it is not a weekend.  It echoes the %day% variable to the screen `20131111` as today is Tuesday 12th Nov here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40964/discussion-between-user1863359-and-foxidrive)

Comment: You said there was an error message and that can happen if you edit the code - you didn't tell me that you edited the code - but as it is posted the code works fine.  Don't just disappear from a chat.  It would be polite to say that you are leaving.

Comment: Well if I ask you a question, 5 minutes later I ask if you are still there, and 10 minutes after that with no response - what do you expect??

Comment: at least I didn't leave you as you said, you can see how many mesage i sent to you, i'am the one who need help here , so why I would leave you without saying anything !!
anyway , i did not modify your code, and it still don't work,
so please can we continue the chat session ?

Comment: are you gone ? i'm still waiting

Comment: the problem in your code is that the variable weekend is always defined so it will makes an endless loop

Comment: Hi FoxiDrive, I have a question , I wanted the Today -2 , (we will suppose that we are the Tuesday so it must return the Friday date )
so I changed the set qty=-1 to set qty=-2 but it doesn't work , can you help me please